# How to get File manipulation to work in Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit

I have some tests that I wrote in JUnit built with Maven that uses the File and FileWriter API, and the tests work on my local machine but not when I try to build it in Jenkins. Is there a special convention that I have to follow to get my tests to work in Jenkins?

In my test file I am initializing some paths for where my resource folder is located:

```
  private String resourcesFolderPath = new File("src/test/resources").getAbsolutePath();
  private String outputFolderPath = resourcesFolderPath + "/output";
  private File outputFolder = new File(outputFolderPath);
```

And here is a test that is failing in Jenkins:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    File file = new File(outputFolder.list()[0]); // File not found exception at this line
    if (!file.exists()) file.mkdirs(); // I added this line after Jenkins build failed, did not fix the problem
    String fileListName = file.getName();

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(outputFolderPath + "/" + fileListName);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    String firstFileName = buffReader.readLine();

    assertTrue(firstFileName.contains("test1.txt"));

    buffReader.close();
  }
```

The output folder contains the file that I want to test, but Jenkins fails with a FileNotFoundException:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jenkins/workspace/utils-feature-branches-ci/file-list/src/test/resources/output/File_List.txt (No such file or directory)
```

The strange thing is that this test works in my local machine when building with Maven, but just not on Jenkins. So my question is how do I modify my code so that this test works with Jenkins? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you like to read something from the resources folder you have to go via `getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/whatever.properties")`. Reading a directory list like you did there is one assumption you have made. The order of the files...the order of files depends on OS/JDK so you have to make no assumption about the order you will get the filenames. Furthermore don't use file names for reading from `src/test/resources` directory.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

While running Test classes through JUnit,`src/test/resources` will be your classpath.

So adding this line will be sufficient for your purpose

```
File file = new File("output");
```

Comment: Thank you, but my question isn't really about JUnit, the output path that I have works already, but it just does not work on Jenkins.